# XHTML, Glassfish, Apache, and Internet Explorer

Tags: apache, internet-explorer-8, xhtml, mime-types

When I run Glassfish on localhost, and trying to load xhtml files on IE8, I get the pages loaded.

I uploaded xhtml files to an Apache Server, and successfully accessed them from Chrom, FF and IE9.

IE8, on the other hand, asks me to download the xhtml files, probably because it doesn't recognize these files as valid html files.

Is it possible to solve this without changing the files to .htm, or add anything to the files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that Internet Explorer (8 or 9) cannot  handle the correct mime type for XHTML.

When you change the extension to html, Apache will set the html mime type.

The solution is to tweak Apache configuration to accommodate this problem.  It can be done through mod_mime or through mod_rewrite.

Here is the mod_rewrite way:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} .*MSIE.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.xhtml$
RewriteRule .* - [T=text/html]
```

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-tipapachexhtml/index.html

Comment: Thanks! If someone encounters this issue: note that "When using the Apache Web server, you can do this in the server config file or in the .htaccess file in an individual directory. ", as remarked in @Akber Choudhry's article.